# Text to speech with Google translation in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I write this function:

```
  playVoice() {
    let audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = `https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=en&client=tw-ob&q=test`;
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  }
```

My goal in writing this function is to convert text to speech. But I get the following error.

> GET
> https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=en&client=tw-ob&q=test
> 404

Comment: 404 means resource not found. If you try loading that URL in your browser what do you see?

Comment: It is downloaded @LajosArpad